# Remove console.log during Angular 6.x library compilation

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 6.x library project and compiling the library with `--prod` does not remove calls to `console.log`. Is there a parameter that will remove all `console.log` calls during compilation?

Answer (score 2):

in main.ts file add this

```
f(your_env === 'prod') { 
   window.console.log = function(){};
}
```

Comment: Does this actually result in the calls being stripped, or does it just redirect them to this noop function?

Answer (score 0):

a simple fix would be

```
if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
      if(window){
        window.console.log=function(){};
      }
    }
```

Comment: _if(window){_ is this really required.

Comment: just to be on the safer side. Not a pro with document or window objects